# Make Macports compile Boost for iOS as well as OS X

Tags: boost, macports

I have used Macports to install Boost on my Mac. So far I've been using the header-only parts of Boost for my iOS project and everything was fine.

Now I need to use one of the compiled libraries. I would like to keep using Macports to keep Boost up to date.

Is there a way to tell the `port` command to compile the libraries for multiple platforms when installing/upgrading?

For the record, I have used `sudo port install boost` to install Boost and I'm at 1.47 now. Using OS X Lion and the SVN version of Macports.

Comment: What libraries are you using from boost?

Comment: Some header-only ones (bind, signals, format) but also filesystem, for instance. And I'd like to use the graph library sometime.

Comment: @TomA can you provide me some hint of how I can use only header of Boost in ios. I am trying to do that but I can't I need to use only headers without libs ... Thanks !!!

Comment: @TomasAndrle, I have similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818262/how-to-build-static-libs-with-fembed-bitcode-using-macports Maybe you can find some answers there. Just need to add bitcode compile option and build boost in static. Worst to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware [MacPorts does not currently have a "platform armv6" or "platform armv7"](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2011-February/013775.html) command so you're out of luck on that front. The [+universal](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/buildUniversal) flag might help with the simulator but obviously won't compile for the handsets.

[aleph7](https://github.com/aleph7) suggests creating [an XCode project](https://github.com/downloads/aleph7/a-coding/xcode-boost.zip) (read his source) as [the Boost build system does not fully support the iOS framework](http://www.a-coding.com/2011/01/building-boost-for-ios.html).

MacPorts stores source packages in `/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles` so you can get-a-symlinking rather than downloading the source as per his instructions.

If you'd prefer a Boost framework for iOS rather than an XCode project, check out [Peter Goodliffe's instructions](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2010/09/building-boost-framework-for-ios-iphone.html).

Comment: Yep, Peter Goodliffe's instructions were the best I could find too. Pity I won't be able to keep the Boost versions in sync with a single command. Oh well. Thanks.